# How to get the jsonp link from this api?

Tags: javascript, json, api, jsonp

I've been googling this forever but I'm just so confused. I'm trying to use the data from this api

https://github.com/artsmia/collection/blob/master/objects/0/1.json

I'm trying to use JSONP since I get cross-origin errors if I don't... Here's what I got...

```
function foo(data) {
    var parsedData = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
    console.log(parsedData.artist);
}

var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://github.com/artsmia/collection/blob/master/objects/0/1.json';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);

foo(script);
```

But this doesn't work. I guess it's because I'm not linking it correctly, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: You can only use JSONP if the api has a JSONP endpoint. There is no way to get it unless the server servers you JSONP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to get the data from the html page. Click on <kbd>raw</kbd> button and use that url. You can't get jsonp from an api that doesn't serve jsonp but the raw endpoint is cors enabled

```js
fetch('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/artsmia/collection/master/objects/0/1.json')
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
```

Comment: Hey this works. Thanks so much!   ..................    EDIT: Although do you know why the raw link works with your code, but when I try it with the one I had it just says "Refused to execute script because its MIME type ('application/json') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled."

Comment: It is an html page at that url and it's not CORS enabled